# How to get hold of an excel sheet by its name using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I have a .xls file which is auto generated through some process. There is only 1 sheet(with a name) in the workbook. When i use the following code, it is not getting hold of the sheet

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

But when i copy the contents of that sheet into a new .xls file in sheet 1, and rerun the code, its working fine. My assumption is, it has to catch hold of any sheet that exists at index 0, then why its not working in the former case and working fine in the latter case? Any ideas?

Comment: What does `workbook.getNumberOfSheets()` return?

Comment: its not even reading that sheet, its throwing an exception, dont know why. Its a valid .xls sheet with a name given to the sheet. However, when i try to create a new sheet inside the workbook, its opening as sheet 1(im surprised here)

Comment: and its a .xls sheet that is generated by a java program and not a user created manual one. There is a difference!